# React Joyride - arrow changes position back to center even though there is margin

Tags: reactjs

Like the title says I have an issue with React Joyride, I want to customize the tooltip without making a custom one, as I do not know how to do that, nor do I think I need a custom one. My issue is that when I set the margin of an arrow it moves back to center when I click next, or to be precise when I move to the next tooltip.
Here's my code:

```
function Tour({ steps }) {
  const INITIAL_STATE = {
    steps: steps,
    key: new Date(),
    run: false,
    continuous: true,
    loading: false,
    stepIndex: 0,
  };

  const [tourState, dispatch] = useReducer(generalReducer, INITIAL_STATE);
  // this useEffect is currently temporary, probably will check if the user has entered for the first time on page where tour is needed
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("tour")) {
      dispatch({ type: tour.START });
    }
  }, []);

  const callback = data => {
    const { action, index, type, status } = data;
    if (action === ACTIONS.CLOSE || (status === STATUS.SKIPPED && tourState.run) || status === STATUS.FINISHED) {
      dispatch({ type: tour.STOP });
    } else if (type === EVENTS.STEP_AFTER || type === EVENTS.TARGET_NOT_FOUND) {
      dispatch({
        type: tour.NEXT_OR_PREV,
        payload: { stepIndex: index + (action === ACTIONS.PREV ? -1 : 1) },
      });
    }
  };

  // I made this in case there is going to be a functionality to start the tour again by pressing a button or something like that
  const startTour = () => {
    dispatch({ type: tour.RESTART });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <JoyRide
        {...tourState}
        callback={callback}
        locale={{
          back: "Previous",
          last: "Confirm",
        }}
        continuous={true}
        showProgress={true}
        floaterProps={{
          styles: {
            arrow: {
              margin: -10,
            },
          },
        }}
        styles={{
          buttonNext: {
            fontSize: "1rem",
            height: "32px",
            width: "71px",
            backgroundColor: "#4e63ce",
            letterSpacing: ".5px",
            borderRadius: "8px",
            fontWeight: "500",
            marginLeft: "16px",
          },
          buttonClose: {
            width: "10.5px",
            height: "10.5px",
          },
          buttonBack: {
            fontSize: "1rem",
            color: "#4e63ce",
            fontWeight: "500",
          },

          tooltipTitle: {
            marginLeft: "9px",
            marginTop: "10px",
            fontSize: "1.8rem",
          },
          tooltipContent: {
            fontSize: "1.2rem",
          },
          tooltipContainer: {
            textAlign: "left",
          },
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

Tour.propTypes = {
  steps: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default Tour;
```

Here's how I want it to look like or here is how it looks like when I set the margin initially:
[image]

Here's what happens when I click next:

[image]

If you know how to fix this I would gladly appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

You should update joyride to the latest version and then try setting `disableScrollParentFix` props to `true`